# Transform character array into integers with python

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I have a piece of data which is in the form of character array:

```
cgcgcg
aacacg
cgcaag
cgcacg
agaacg
cacaag
agcgcg
cgcaca
cacaca
agaacg
cgcacg
cgcgaa
```

Notice that each column consists of only two types characters. I need to transform them into integers 0 or 1, based on their percentage in the column. For instance in the 1st column, there are 8 c's and 4 a's, so c is in majority, then we need to code it as 0 and the other as 1.

Using zip() I can transpose this array in python, and get each column into a list:

```
In [28]: lines = [l.strip() for l in open(inputfn)]

In [29]: list(zip(*lines))
Out[29]: 
[('c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c'),
 ('g', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'g'),
 ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c'),
 ('g', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'g'),
 ('c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a'),
 ('g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'a')]
```

It's not necessary to transform them strictly into integers, i.e. 'c' to '0' or 'c' to int(0) will both be ok, since we are going to write them to a tab delimited file anyway.

Comment: I'm guessing, based on the letters you have here, that we're talking DNA base pairs? If so, gotta say, I don't think it's a good idea to have 0/1 be ambiguous. Why does it matter that the most-common nucleotide be '0'? (or am I wrong about the DNA thing?)

Comment: What if the majority is `g`? `c` should be 1, `a` is 0...

Comment: @AdamKG yeah, this is DNA stuff. It's no ambiguous, because though we have 4 bases, they always appear in pairs, i.e. A with T, C with G, so we only need two numbers to denote them when it comes to data analysis.

Comment: @septi By majority I mean in each column, or each list in the result I showed above. If g is majority, then it's denoted as 0. There couldn't be conflict since there are only two types of characters in each list.

Comment: No, I mean it being ambiguous whether your 0 represents the a/t pair or the c/g pair. Why not have it be consistent throughout the dataset?

Comment: @AdamKG oh, i see. 0 represents majority, not a specific pair.

Comment: (shrug) fair enough. Answer below should work.

Comment: @AdamKG In this case majority means healthy and normal, rare alleles do not necessarily cause disease, but disease-causal alleles must be rare, due to natural selection. That's why we care about which one is majority, but not so much about the specific pair. Hope this has answered your question. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
lis = [('c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c'),
 ('g', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'g'),
 ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c'),
 ('g', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'g'),
 ('c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a'),
 ('g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'a')]
def solve(lis):
    for row in lis:
        item1, item2 = set(row)
        c1, c2 = row.count(item1), row.count(item2)
        dic = {item1 : int(c1 < c2), item2 : int(c2 < c1)}
        yield [dic[x] for x in row]
...         
>>> list(solve(lis))
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
def solve(lis):
    for row in lis:
        c = Counter(row)
        maxx = max(c.values())
        yield [int(c[x] < maxx) for x in row]
...         
>>> pprint(list(solve(lis)))
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Everything works well except it should be `int(c1 < c2)` in the dictionary. Thanks!